# how to check a value exists in array in quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

```
  const myproducts = ref([])
  const items = ref([
    { id: 1, item: 'Vaporub 50Gm' , barcode: '123456'},
    { id: 2, item: 'Herbal Cool Oil (300+100)Ml', barcode: '123456' },
    { id: 3, item: 'live Oil Bp 70Ml', barcode: '123456' }
  ]

 const selectedProducts = function(id) {
   var exists = myproducts.value.some(function(field) {
     return field.id === id;
   });

   if (!exists) {
     myproducts.value.push( '{id:'+ id +', qty:'+ 1 +'}' );
     console.log("clicked on ", id );
   } else {
     console.log("Already exist on ", id );
   }
}
```

How to check if id exists in `myproducts` array? I used above function but no result.

Comment: Is The typeof id paramater is a number? It should be a number because you are checking with ===

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutley wrong:

`myproducts.value.push( '{id:'+ id +', qty:'+ 1 +'}' );`

You try to create an object by concatenating strings.

Just use an object:

```
myproducts.value.push({ id, qty: 1 });
```